# Difficulty understanding Angular / JS syntax (?.)

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi i am looking at the following Angular code, which is an error message div if the user does not enter their name in the Name field.

```
<div *ngIf ="userName.errors?.required && username.touched" class="alert alert-danger"> Name is required</div>
```

I understand that this div will show if the Name field is touched and the username has not been entered in the Name field

But I'm not sure i follow the `?.` syntax. How should i read it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's called the [Safe Navigation Operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator). It's used if you expect an object to be possibly `null` and you need to access its properties. That is to prevent an error which is caused by accessing properties of null values.

Comment: got it... and thanks for the link... a quick follow-up query... in the ngIf why can't we just check for `userName.required` as opposed to `userName.errors?.required`

Comment: Because based on [Angular Form Validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation), `errors` is a list of validation errors (e.g. `required`, `minlength`) that you can use to validate your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

this `?.`  means that only check this property if it have value, in other words, this will ignore it if `userName.errors` for any reason is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In `C#` , it is called `Null Propagation`. See below codes, they express the same meaning.

```
var name = _currentTpl != null ? _currentTpl.TplName : null;

var name = _currentTpl?.TplName;
```

In Angular , it is called `safe navigation operator`. Actually, there is no difference.